(Geometry Nodes) How can I get more petals in toward the center and have them curl more than the outside petals?
I followed a tutorial to make this flower using geometry nodes via the matrix nodes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dl4iCrksryM
I modified it to look a bit more like a rose but I'm having a heck of a time getting it just right. It looks fine from specific angles but you can tell from above that the middle is lacking.
So just like the title, I want the middle to curl and have more petals than the outside and also try to not clip through each other in GN.



